# Sqldeveloper /as sysdba connection

Tags: sqldeveloper, jdbc, oracle-11g

I'm a total newbie in Oracle.

I installed Oracle 11g XE R2. 
Also I installed SqlDeveloper 3.2.20.09 version.

I generated auto connections, and I have 2 connections. 
One is: /as sysdba 
and another: system-XE

I successfully connect to system-XE, but when I try to connect as sysdba in SQLdeveloper (in same time I can connect trough SQL command line) I get this error:

```
java.lang.Error: Incompatible version of libocijdbc[Jdbc:112030, Jdbc-OCI:112020
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection$1.run(T2CConnection.java:3557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.loadNativeLibrary(T2CConnection.java:3550)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.logon(T2CConnection.java:266)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:552)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.<init>(T2CConnection.java:162)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CDriverExtension.getConnection(T2CDriverExtension.java:53)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:526)
at oracle.jdeveloper.db.adapter.AbstractConnectionCreator.getConnection(AbstractConnectionCreator.java:153)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.standalone.connection.RaptorConnectionCreator.getConnection(RaptorConnectionCreator.java:195)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.dialogs.conn.ConnectionPrompt.promptForPassword(ConnectionPrompt.java:67)
at oracle.jdeveloper.db.adapter.DatabaseProvider.getConnection(DatabaseProvider.java:321)
at oracle.jdeveloper.db.adapter.DatabaseProvider.getConnection(DatabaseProvider.java:254)
at oracle.jdevimpl.db.adapter.CADatabaseFactory.createConnectionImpl(CADatabaseFactory.java:60)
at oracle.javatools.db.DatabaseFactory.createConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:534)
at oracle.javatools.db.DatabaseFactory.createDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:208)
at oracle.jdeveloper.db.DatabaseConnections.getDatabase(DatabaseConnections.java:607)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections$ConnectionInfo.getDatabase(Connections.java:172)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections.getConnection(Connections.java:1064)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections.getConnection(Connections.java:1045)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.DatabaseConnection.openConnectionImpl(DatabaseConnection.java:115)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.AbstractConnectionNode.getConnection(AbstractConnectionNode.java:30)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.ConnectionFilter.getFactory(ConnectionFilter.java:94)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.ConnectionFilter$1.doWork(ConnectionFilter.java:119)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.ConnectionFilter$1.doWork(ConnectionFilter.java:104)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTask.call(RaptorTask.java:193)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$RaptorFutureTask.run(RaptorTaskManager.java:515)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Any help would be really appreciated since now I was searching for the solution almost 3 hours.

Comment: Try upgrading Java to latest version, there are some incompatibilities, according to your log.

Comment: I have Version 7 Update 25 so :/

Comment: How are you trying to connect? Can you provide a minimal example of code that causes this error?

Comment: I have default OS authentication for sysdba, and I only tried to connect as usual in SqlDeveloper. It works for other connections, but not for the sysdba since it it OS authentication (probably that is the resion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it. In the sqldeveloper/jdbc/lib folder replace the ojdbc6dms.jar and ojdbc6.jar files with the same files, but version Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.2.0) JDBC Drivers :)

Answer (score 7):

Source: [SQL developer 3.1 shows error Incompatible version of libocijdbc](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2346683) (Oracle Community)

---

1. Create tnsnames.ora file
2. Open SQL Developer and set tnsnames directory
   tools->Preferences->Database->advanced->Tnsnames Directory
3. In SQL Developer, UNCHECK: 
   tools->Preferences->Database->advanced->use oci/thick driver
4. New connection connection type TNS -> Network Alias (pick from list)
5. Try connection

Answer (score 2):

The first error message seems to be reasonably clear:

```
java.lang.Error: Incompatible version of libocijdbc[Jdbc:112030, Jdbc-OCI:112020
```

For whatever reason, the version of libocijdbc which is being found (apparently version 112020) is not compatible with the jdbc version found (112030).  You might want to consider  tracking down version 112030 of libocijdbc, or switching things around so that version 110230 of libocijdbc is found first.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: It's not reasonably clear if you don't even have a JAR by that name anywhere that the program could find it. It doesn't even tell you what it actually incompatible with what else.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and figured out that I was using different TNS network alias and connector identifier. Check those first

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error but a different reason.
I was using jdbc url like below.

jdbc:oracle:oci:@//localhost:1521/servicename

I changed it to below and worked fine.

jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/servicename